# Not able to fetch data from multiple hasMany relations - laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

I wanted to fetch whole data from all 4 relations: `education`,`documents`,`references`,`skills` along with the `User` table's data. The following query only returns data from user table but not from any of the 4 relations although they have matching data in them. I have added its screenshot at the bottom. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

**Controller**

```
$u = User::where('id', $id)->with(['education','documents','references','skills'])->get();
dd($u);
```

**User Model**

```
public function education(){
    return $this->hasMany(StaffEducation::class,'id','user_id');
}
public function documents(){
    return $this->hasMany(StaffDocuments::class,'id','user_id');
}
public function references(){
    return $this->hasMany(StaffReferences::class,'id','user_id');
}
public function skills(){
    return $this->hasMany(StaffSkills::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way

`return $this->hasMany(StaffEducation::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

```
public function education(){
    return $this->hasMany(StaffEducation::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

Use the same for the rest of your relations